# Frameworks and Libraries Compatibility

Tags: reactjs, electron, structure

Everyone.
I ask some abstruse question.

I'm making an Desktop Application based on 'Electron'.
As I study, I learn a lot of things.

But, I can't constitute my project structure.

**First of all, I'm using electron and create-raect-app (added react-redux, react-router-dom).

And, I want to add both nest.js and next.js.**

So, Are they working well?
Or do I change some of them?

I'm searching for a day, but I'm not sure 100%.

I guess Next.js is the framework of react.
Then, **If I use Next.js, is react unnessesary?**

I feel like my head is getting dizzy...

**[Questions Summary]**

1. Is Electron + create-react-app (added react-redux, react-router-dom) + next.js + nest.js working well?
2. If I use Next.js, is react unnessesary?

Comment: Any tech stack that works in Google Chrome will work on Electron, you can use any framework + any library you want. Next.js is a library for React, so you will need React for it. Next.js is usually used for websites, not for Electron apps since you don't need server side rendering and pre-rendering in your app.

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman I'm late to reply. Thanks you for your answering. My wonder is gone thank to you.